# How to set checkbox label position without using formMultiCheckbox(...) in ZF2?

Tags: checkbox, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, form-helpers

I want to be able to set the label position:

- for the entire element and
- (in case of checkboxes / radio buttons) additionally for every single checkbox / radio button.

I have a form, that is build like this:

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url());
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>

<?php $fooFieldset = $form->get('foo'); ?>

<div id="fieldset-foo" class="fieldset-container col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate($fooFieldset->getLabel()); ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php foreach ($fooFieldset as $element) : ?>
            <div class="form-group <?php if($this->formElementErrors($element)) echo 'error' ?>">
                <?php $element->setOption('label_position', FormRow::LABEL_PREPEND); /* not working! */ ?>
                <label><?php echo $this->translate($element->getLabel()); ?></label>
                <div>
                    <?php $element->setAttribute('class', 'form-control'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->formElement($element); ?>
                    <?php if ($this->formElementErrors($element)) : ?>
                        <div class="message-error"><?php echo $this->formElementErrors($element) ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- futher fieldsets -->

<!-- fields without fieldsets -->


<?php
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form);
?>
```

That means, I'm not calling the `formRow(...)` or `formMultiCheckbox(...)` and cannot configure the `label_position` on this way. The setting an option directly on the element (`$element->setOption('label_position', FormRow::LABEL_PREPEND)`) does not work at all -- neither for the entire element nor for checkboxes / radio buttons.

**How to get it working and set the label position (1. for the entire element; 2. for the checkboxes / radio buttons) here?**

Comment: "The setting an option directly on the element ($element->setOption('label_position', FormRow::LABEL_PREPEND)) does not work at all" ------ Meaning you are probably doing it wrong, if you var_dump your $element in your foreach you'll see his properties. Those are use for rendering.
You could also make your own rendering classe : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/form.decorators.individual.html

Comment: @Unex Well I have expressed myself wrong, I meant, that there is no (visible) effect. Thank for your link to the docu. It's the version 2.1. 2.2 was the last version, where usage of form decorators is explained. As far I know, form decorators have been removed from the framework.